# "Old" price is shown in net, final price is in gross; both should be displayed gross (Magento 2.1.2)

Tags: magento2, tax

We are currently experiencing a problem where the "old price" is shown in net (products are configured to have net prices, Magento is configured to display GROSS prices based on eachs product tax), however, the final price is displayed correctly. Also, there is a bug where the correct old price is shown when you select a specific configurable products entity.

Here you can see, that the "Sonderangebots"-Price is 49,90€, which is *fine*. However, the old price is the configured NET price, which is WRONG. It should show the correctly calculated gross price as well. There has been *no* modification to the specific template.

[image]

This is our backend configuration:

**configured to handle net prices, which are configured on product basis** 
[image]

**configured to show prices including tax** 
[image]

What do I need to change?

Comment: Please download Magento 2.1.3 with Sample Data & test. U get where u r wrong

Comment: Updating is not a possibility, as the customer doesn't want to invest time here nor does he want the update. :/

Comment: I'm not saying that. Just check in default version whether it works fine or not

Comment: Have u checked @Max?

Comment: @AnkitShah not really yet, I'm rather looking forward to a fix for this; I do not totally understand what information I'd get from setting a Magento up, that I cannot use anyhow, just to check if it works with a newer version doesn't seem to do the trick for me, so maybe you can give me a little more information! That'd be great.

Comment: Calculation Settings -> Apply Discount On Prices Change it to Excluding Tax
Price Display Settings -> Make Both Excluding Tax
Shopping Cart Display Settings -> Make Both Excluding Tax.
In short 1st make all Excluding Tax. Then make one by one "Including Tax" & then check price. Make 1 Including Tax & Check Price & so on. In ur case u have to do 5 time

Comment: Any update @Max?

Comment: No, because we need a fix for that version, not for another one. :/